# Why this type of implicit conversion is illegal?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I write the following implicit conversion in scala:

```
  implicit def strToInt2(str: String):Int = {
    str.toInt
  }
```

But it rises this compilation error:

```
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : str.type (with underlying type String)
 required: ?{val toInt: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method augmentString in object Predef of type (x: String)scala.collection.
immutable.StringOps
 and method toi in object $iw of type (str: String)Int
 are possible conversion functions from str.type to ?{val toInt: ?}
           str.toInt
           ^
```

If I remove the return type, just declare it like this:

```
  implicit def strToInt2(str: String) = {
    str.toInt
  }
```

It compiles successfully. Can anyone tell me what's the difference between the two ?

Comment: Don't know exact answer, but I suppose that there are one implicit conversion string -> int in Predef. So, adding new conversion of that types makes things ambiguous.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, let's start with the beginning, why does it fail in the first case:

1. You try to define an implicit method that transforms a `String` into an `Int` and to do so you call `toInt`.
2. Unfortunately, `toInt` is not a part of the `String` class. Thus, the compiler needs to find an implicit to convert `str` in something that has a `toInt:Int` method.
3. Fortunately, `Predef.augmentString` convert a `String` into a `StringOps`, which has such a method.
4. But the `Int` type also have such a method and AS you define a return type, the method `strToInt2` can be called recursively, and as the method is implicit, it can be applied to transform something with a `toInt:Int` function.
5. The compiler doesn't know which implicit method to use (between yours and `Predef.augmentString` and throws an error.

In the second case, as you omit the return type, the `strToInt2` function cannot be recursive, and there are no longer two candidates to transform the `String`.

BUT if after this definition, you try: `"2".toInt`, the error is back: you now have two ways to obtain something with a `toInt:Int`function when you have a `String`.

Comment: So ... how do we fix this? I need a `stringToInt` method. I can define it like this: `def string2Int(string: String): Int = Predef.augmentString(string).toInt` to resolve the ambiguity, but unfortunately this breaks an explicit `"2".toInt` in the same scope (it no longer compiles). Is there any way to get both implicit String -> Int conversion and explicit `string.toInt` in the same scope?